# How do I allow autocomplete for everything except AWT and Swing in Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, ide, code-completion

AWT and Swing have almost the same names for everything in JavaFX, so I find myself going through the items by their package, finding the FX entries, and then looking at the documentation.

I know it's possible for modules, but this is a core JDK library bundled with everything else

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can exclude specific packages from auto import in IntelliJ settings.

`Settings` > `Editor` > `General` > `Auto Import` > `Java` > `Exclude from Import and Completion`. There you can add packages `javax.swing` and `javax.awt`.

You can find more details about this setting in the [IntelliJ manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/excluding-classes-from-auto-import.html#r_Excluding_Classes_from_Auto-Import.xmld235936e72).